# vim how to keep cursor position while copying text

Tags: vim, windows, vi, gvim

I am (having to) using gvim in windows.
I was used to the linux environment where when I select text using mouse the cursor position wont change.
Now , with gvim in windows,

My problem is something like this -

1. while I am editing in line 6
2. and when I am having to copy "hellovim" from line 3
3. and when I click with mouse on "hellovim" to copy it
4. then the cursor gets moved to "hellovim" on line 3
5. where as I would like the cursor to stay on line 6

How can I do this

Comment: Are the gvim versions the same? Same configurations?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226025/vim-how-to-keep-cursor-position-while-copying-text; please don't post the same question to multiple sites in parallel!

Answer (score 1):

There is no option in the gvim doc that allows to do exactly what you want when editing your vimrc file. FYI, options are available here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#CursorMoved

However, you can add the following code to your vimrc file:

```
augroup NO_CURSOR_MOVE_ON_SELECTION
  au!
  au MenuPopup * let g:oldmouse=&mouse | set mouse=
  au CursorMoved * if exists('g:oldmouse') | let &mouse=g:oldmouse | unlet g:oldmouse | endif
augroup EN
```

What it does:
It records the cursor position on RightClick event (the one that displays the contextual menu).
Then if you do a selection, the cursor will remain to the recorded position (and will not change).
Once done, the recorded posisition is deleted on cursor movement, e.g. hitting a row, so that you can still move the cursor by click.

Of course you can use another event than the right click.

PS: it is like you create a "selection" state, activated by right clicking (or anything else you prefer) and deactivated by cursor move with keyboard. During this state, all your selections won't change the cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your mouse option settings.

```
gvim afile
```

To show your current options do

```
:set
```

Look for the `mouse=<some value>` it's probably `mouse=a` this means the mouse works in all modes. You can select which modes the mouse will operate. So

```
:mouse=nvc
```

Will set the mouse only to work in, Normal, Visual and Command mode (insert mode omitted)

Modes can be:

```
n = Normal mode
v = Visual mode
c = Command mode
i = Insert mode
a = all modes
```

Now when you are inserting text you can still select with mouse and cursor will remain at your current insert position.